# Resizing an image in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, image-processing, delphi-xe, image-resizing

I got a jpeg image in which is 1020x780, I am trying to resize this to 111x85 (which is in proportion) but it comes out pixelated.

I am tried just

a) Assign the image to a TImage component and set the Scaled/Resize property.

b) The resize code here http://www.delphigroups.info/2/4/313095.html

c) The resize code here http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1896

However they all come out pixelated.

If I resize in Photoshop then it comes out nice. Getting it THAT good would be ideal, however I know they spent a lot of time/code into resize so something even halfway between would be great.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Graphics32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphics32/) library. It implements various image resampling and transformation algorithms for 32-bit bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks, I got it installed under XE - but can't find any good examples of how to resample - got link?

Answer (score 5):

In my blog I talk about resize images using/implementing antialiasing.
Read [the article and test the code here](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=296). It's writed in Spanish but you can use authomatic translate. In any case you can read only the code.

See the difference of apply and not apply the code:

[image]

The code work with BMP, but you can convert the image first and apply it.

Comment: Off-topic here, but dude! Interesting blog! I wanted to suggest it to DelphiFeeds.com, but I see that it's already been rejected. Bummer. Maybe you should consider writing in English to reach a wider audience?  The contents of your blog are way more interesting than all the self-promotion, boring conference announcements and visual studio tips that I often find via DelphiFeeds.com

Comment: +1 neftali, opino lo mismo que wouter si escribieras tu blog en ingles tendrías una gran audiencia.

Comment: Thank you both. This is a topic I've thought several times, but still I not decide.  The necesary time and my English are two overhead obstacles that I must solve/jump. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the built-in TImage for scaling, you could use an external library or component, e.g. ImageMagick or some off-the-shelf component. There exists at least one Pascal wrapper for ImageMagick

http://wiki.freepascal.org/PascalMagick)

, but I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used HiComponents ImageEn library to resize an image down to approx 250 pixels.  It was a while ago, but I recall that the results were quite pleasing.  http://www.hicomponents.com/main/products/products-imageenvcl - it's free now, and well worth a look if you're doing any graphics programming in Delphi.

Comment: the above link is not woking :(